# Scalar found where operator expected when I try to copy a hash from another module

Tags: perl, hash

```
Scalar found where operator expected at /pgfs1/eng/hchian2/bin/soc/fc_net_tracer.pl line 158, near "%hash_build_db::$cblock"
        (Missing operator before $cblock?)
syntax error at /pgfs1/eng/hchian2/bin/soc/fc_net_tracer.pl line 158, near "%hash_build_db::$cblock"
Execution of /pgfs1/eng/hchian2/bin/soc/fc_net_tracer.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I am trying to copy a hash from another module, but this problem error is blocking me.

The code I am using to reference the hash I created in `hash_build_db.pm` is

```
use hash_build_db;
%$cblock = %hash_build_db::$cblock;
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be

```
%$cblock = %hash_build_db::cblock;
```

if you have `cblock` hash inside `hash_build_db` package, and `$cblock` is hashref.

Comment: %$cblock have to %{$cblock} by use strict or not?

Comment: @AlexTape no, those two things mean the same thing, strict or not.

Comment: @AlexTape `%$cblock` is short version of `%{ $cblock }`, and dereferencing alone is not affected by `strict`

Comment: ah ok.. i prevent to doing this because of use warnings and diagnostics.. even then a warnings appears ;)